# C++ sort iteration sometimes gives wrong value

Tags: c++

```
tour_indexes.clear();
for (int i=0; i<num_of_cities; i++)
{
    tour_indexes.push_back(i);
}

mt19937 gen(random_engine());
uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0, 1);

// Sort indexes based on comparing values in tour. Choose at random if equal
sort(tour_indexes.begin(), tour_indexes.end(),
     [&tour, &dis, &gen](int &i1, int &i2)
{
    if (tour[i1] == tour[i2])
    {
        return dis(gen) < 0.5;
    }
    return tour[i1] < tour[i2];
});
```

This gives me a segfault on `tour[i1] == tour[i2]`, and when debugging I find that it is because `i2` is sometimes (seemingly non deterministic) way bigger than it should be. F.ex 403163787 (it varies) when `tour_indexes` is f.ex 0 - 20 (and I've double checked at error time that `tour_indexes` does not contain `i2`).

This all happens in a member function in a class containing the member variable `tour_indexes`. The class object is in a shared_ptr if that is relevant. Any ideas what might be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Including the definition and initialization of `tour` and `num_of_cities`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, in principle.  In practise "segfault from std::sort" means "my comparison operator is not valid" at least 99% of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparator does not provide a strict weak ordering.  Specifically, if `tour[i1] == tour[i2]` there is a 50/50 chance that it will return true or false *and the answer is not stable* (it must be).

If your comparison function does not provide a strict weak ordering, the behaviour is undefined, and a seg-fault is one plausible behaviour.

I suggest using `return i1 < i2;` This will break the tie in a stable way.

Alternatively, there is no need to break the tie at all.  Just use

```
[&tour](int i1, int i2) 
{
    return tour[i1] < tour[i2]; 
}
```

`std::sort` is quite happy with a *weak* ordering; which means that both `cmp(i1,i2)` and `cmp(i2,i1)` may return false.  What it can't cope with is them both returning true (or two calls with the same arguments returning *different* values.)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the randomization in the compare operator. Perhaps the sort algortihm fails becuase both i1 < i2 and i2 < i1 can be true if elements are equal.

sort already gives a random order if equal element and stable_sort gives a deterministic order of equal elements in the array.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know sort gave a random answer if equal, although it seems to give the same answer every time.

Comment: It doesn't give a *random* answer.  It gives an *unpredictable* answer.  There is nothing in the standard to forbid `std::sort` just calling `std::stable_sort`.  In practise, I would expect `std::sort` to just give whatever answer the quicksort algorithm gives.

Comment: @Freddard -- Too bad you didn't run your program under Visual Studio debug runtime, since it detects this issue by calling the `sort` functor twice to see if the return value is the same with the arguments switched,   If the return answer was the same, the program would have halted with an assertion.